# Locating focus and semi latus-rectum of conic by R&C construction.

Tags: conic-sections, geometric-construction, solid-geometry

A cone semi-vertex angle $\gamma$  is cut by a plane inclined at angle $\alpha$ to symmetry axis. Length of perpendicular on plane from the cone vertex is $q$.

[image: Conic section sketch]

It is known that eccentricity

$$ \epsilon =\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\gamma} $$

can be calculated. But can the semi latus-rectum $p$ or its length $\dfrac {q}{p}=f(\alpha,\gamma)$ be ***represented/found by geometric construction***?

Thanks in advance for  suggestion of a simple Ruler/Compass  construction.

Finding foci for hyperbola intersection drawing direct tangents of Dandelin spheres.. is this how it is done?

[image: Finding Foci Hyperbola Intersection]

Comment: If you can find the focus by construction it shouldn't be hard - from there it's just Pythagoras.

Comment: It is known  $F$ should be along projection line  from vertex $V$  but nothing further at this stage.

Comment: Is Joachimsthal 's thm in differential geometry relevant here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $V$ and $W$ are the vertices of the conic section, and $VV'$, $WW'$ are perpendicular to the axis of the cone, then the latus rectum is given by (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3214811/getting-the-minimum-radius-of-curvature-of-a-conic-section/3215080#3215080) for details):
$$
2p={VV'\cdot WW'\over VW}.
$$
This is valid for an ellipse or hyperbola: the equation for a parabola can be recovered by letting $OW\to\infty$, where $O$ is the cone vertex.

[image]

EDIT.

See below for a ruler-and-compass construction of foci $F$ and $G$, based on the formula for the distance between a focus and the center of the ellipse
$c={1\over2}\sqrt{VW^2−VV'\cdot WW'}$.

[image]

Comment: Can the focus  be now marked from above definition with a point here or in any other projection/view? Is the intersection of axis of symmetry and (red) cutting plane projection the focus $F$ ?

Comment: By the same formulas given in the linked answer we can find the distance between a focus and the center of the ellipse: $$c={1\over2}\sqrt{VW^2-VV'\cdot WW'}.$$ The focus is not, in general, the intersection between the plane and the axis of the cone.

Comment: Is it like trisection problem of an angle that is proved to be impossible by Euler?

Comment: I don't see anything impossible in this case: you can easily construct all the above lengths.

Comment: I forget to mention Ruler and Compass

Comment: You can easily construct all the above lengths WITH RULER AND COMPASS.

Comment: Proceeding the above side projection (or any other projection of conic curve) how to locate the focus using R&C... that  puzzles me.

Comment: In my mind all these are related. Please feel free to suggest any re-edit, or deletion recasting to another question etc. and of course apologies if it appears that I changed the goalpost in question.

Comment: The foci can be located by Dandelin spheres. In your figure you can construct a circle with center on the cone’s axis, tangent to the sides of the cone and to the cutting plane. The point of tangency on the cutting plane is a focus.

Comment: See my edit for an explicit construction: I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for the comments. It helped here and also connect to previous things (Dandelin spheres).

Comment: For hyperbolic section is it the way Dandelin spheres are  contacted with direct tangents? (spheres in different cone sheets ?).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a geometric construction of the foci and latus rectum of an ellipse based on the Dandelin spheres:

[image]

Given a cone with vertex at $V$ and semi-vertex angle $\gamma$ cut by a plane at angle $\alpha$ to the axis of symmetry,
in a plane through the axis of symmetry perpendicular to the cutting plane
the cutting plane intersects the cone at points $A$ and $B$
so that $AB$ is the major axis of the ellipse.
Bisect angle $\angle VAB$ and let $P$ be the intersection of the angle bisector with the axis of symmetry. Drop a perpendicular from $P$ to $AB$ intersecting $AB$ at $F.$
Then $F$ is a focus of the ellipse and $PF$ is a radius of the corresponding Dandelin sphere.

The other focus is similarly constructed by bisecting the angle $\angle B$ as shown in the figure (the other bisector would give us $P$ again),
finding the intersection $Q$ of the bisector and the axis of symmetry,
and dropping a perpendicular from $Q$ to $F'$ on $AB$; then $F'$ is the other focus
and $QF'$ is a radius of its Dandelin sphere.

A plane through $F$ perpendicular to the axis of symmetry intersects the cone in a circle perpendicular to the plane of the figure,
with diameter $CD$ in the plane of the figure.
The semicircle $CD$ in the plane of the figure is congruent to one half of that circle.
Construct a line through $F$ perpendicular to the diameter $CD$ intersecting the semicircle at $G.$ Then $FG$ is the semi-latus rectum.

There is a corresponding construction for the foci and semi-latus rectum of a hyperbola.
The construction for the parabola has only one sphere and one focus.